# обращение к элементу события через this в функции

Tags: javascript

Вопрос с целью приближения понимания к `this`.
В хроме этот код работает, в мозилле нет. Просматриваю через отладчик. В хроме значение `this = window`, в мозилле `this` это объект функции. Если не затруднит, в ответе пример с объяснением и вообще правильный подход к пониманию ?

```js
function showTarget(event) {
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    result.innerHTML = this.event.type + ':' + this.event.target;
}
```

```html
<p id="result">
    Щас что-то будет!
</p>

<p onmouseover="showTarget()">
        Просто мышкой поводить
</p>
<input onkeypress="showTarget()" type="text"/>Чё-нить ввести
<br>
</br>
<input id="flag" onchange="showTarget()" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="flag">
   Здесь установить флажок
</label>
<br>
</br>
<button onclick="showTarget()" type="button">
   Просто Жать
</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И там и там `this` - это `window`.
Просто хром создает глобальное свойство `event`, которое вы читаете, а мозилла - нет. Там евент нужно пробрасывать как аргумент.

Вот так будет работать и там и там:

```js
function showTarget(event) {
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    result.innerHTML = event.type + ':' + event.target;
}
```

```html
<p id="result">
    Щас что-то будет!
</p>

<p onmouseover="showTarget(event)">
        Просто мышкой поводить
</p>
<input onkeypress="showTarget(event)" type="text"/>Чё-нить ввести
<br>
</br>
<input id="flag" onchange="showTarget(event)" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="flag">
   Здесь установить флажок
</label>
<br>
</br>
<button onclick="showTarget(event)" type="button">
   Просто Жать
</button>
```

PS инлайн обработчики - плохая практика